# Recreate lists (ballots) from counted results

Tags: r

I am at a loss, I feel as if I am finding the answer... but I have been unable to do so. I really don't know where to start

I have the results from ranked voting:
It shows how many votes (100 voters) each candidate (5 candidates) got for each place (reproducible data is at the bottom):

```
Name 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th
Can1  50   0  15  25  10
Can2  15  25   0  10  50
Can3  25  50  10   0  15
Can4   0  10  50  15  25
Can5  10  15   0   0   0
```

I am trying to recreate ballots from the results, 100 ballots like this (also, some ballots have not been filled completely):

```
Ballot1:   Can1, Can3, Can4, Can5, Can2
Ballot2:   Can1, Can3, Can5
Ballot3:   Can3, Can5, Can2, Can1, Can4 
...
Ballot100: Can2, Can5, Can1, Can4
```

I need to do this with 60 candidates and more than 1000 votes.

---

```
voting.results <- structure(list(X1 = c("Can1", "Can2", "Can3", "Can4", "Can5"), 
`1place` = c(50L, 15L, 25L, 0L, 10L), `2place` = c(0L, 25L, 
50L, 10L, 15L), `3place` = c(15L, 0L, 10L, 50L, 0L), `4place` = c(25L, 
10L, 0L, 15L, 0L), `5place` = c(10L, 50L, 15L, 25L, 0L)), .Names = c("X1", 
"1place", "2place", "3place", "4place", "5place"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `1place` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), `2place` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), `3place` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), `4place` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), `5place` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("X1", "1place", "2place", "3place", 
"4place", "5place")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: What is the recreation logic for the ballots?

Comment: This can't be solved exactly. You could simulate, but you still wouldn't take things into account such as that some candidates are more likely to end up on a single ballot together.

Comment: Regarding recreation logic... Not really something I have thought about. just as random distribution as possible.

@Axeman I thought that perhaps one could create the ballots with everyone in the right places for the first 1st place, than randomize and alot of if statements: like for 2nd place, if can1 is in first; skip, else write name here (hope this can be understood.). and than, for each iteration (each place), randomization of the list.

I have been thinking that perhaps simular methods to creating a suduko board can be used... but I am uncertain as to how.

Answer (score 1):

at the beginning would be nice to have this dataset with each candidates and his/her all performances. What was done below it's just repeating each row (candidate, place) by the time it's occurred in `voting.results`. 
`df1` is a number of specific places by candidate.

```
library(magrittr);library(dplyr)
df1 <- 
voting.results %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  mutate( variable = as.integer(gsub("place","",variable) )) %>%
  rename(place=variable,can=X1)
head(df1)

#    can place value
# 1 Can1     1    50
# 2 Can2     1    15
# 3 Can3     1    25
# 4 Can4     1     0
# 5 Can5     1    10
# 6 Can1     2     0
```

And `df2` is a dataset with row per each performance.

```
df2 <- 
  df1[ rep(row.names(df1), df1$value) , ] %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  arrange(place)

head(df2)

#   can place id
# 1 Can1     1  1
# 2 Can1     1  2
# 3 Can1     1  3
# 4 Can1     1  4
# 5 Can1     1  5
# 6 Can1     1  6
```

We know that all events have it's winners, so we can initiate each separate event with first candidate (Assuming there is no ex-qequo). And then in every `for( e in 1:length(events) )` add candidates at other places. Added candidates are substracted from initial dataset.
If some individuals from initial dataset are not assigned (`nrow(temp)>1`), then process is repeated until it's finish with success.

```
i <- 0
temp <- data.frame(1)

while(nrow(temp)>0){
  i <- i + 1
  temp    <- df2[ sample(1:nrow(df2)),]
  events <- temp %>% filter(place==1) %>% split(1:nrow(.))

  for( e in 1:length(events) ){
    for( p in sort( unique(temp$place) ) ){

      inAlready <- events[[e]]
      toInput   <- 
        temp %>% 
        filter( !can %in% inAlready$can & place == p) %>%
        .[1,]

      events[[e]] <- rbind( inAlready , toInput )

    }

    events[[e]]$event <- e

    idToExclude <- lapply( events , function(x) x$id) %>% unlist
    temp %<>% filter(!id %in% idToExclude)

  }
}

all <- 
  bind_rows(events) %>%
  arrange(event, place) %>%
  filter(!is.na(id))
```

I don't know if it's perfect solution, and how many iterations are necessary, but I hope this will help you find perfect solution. Anyway, probably there is more than one final solutions, so the perfect reproducibility could be impossible. I'm curious if there is some operational-research-like method to solve this problem.

Enjoy and good luck!